# Getting error 405 when sending request on express route in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, http, next.js

I create routes on Express js in Next js. When i deployed on hosting and sent request on route i getting error 405, but when i do same on localhost everything all right.

I cant understand that is this?

[image]

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' //true false
const nextApp = next({ dev })
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler() //part of next config

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const apiRoutes = require("./routes");
app.use('/api', apiRoutes) 
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
    console.log('asdfasdfasdfd')
    return handle(req,res)
})
app.listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`ready at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your express config has problem.
your express server must be like this:

```js
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app)
const app = next({ dir: '.', dev })

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()
  server.post('/api', (req, res) => {
    handler(req, res, req.url)
  )
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    handler(req, res, req.url)
  })

}
```

check the code for `server.get` and `server.post` or other http methods.

Error 405 tells that the method is not allowed.

Comment: My express config is like this but i also add server.use("/api", require(".routes/api")) for connect my routes

Comment: what is your cors middleware initialization in nextjs?

Comment: I don't use cors in this project. It's important?

Comment: no not important. test with `GET` method and see if it works or not.

Comment: If i send get request i get 404, if i send post request i get 405

Comment: add a console.log to your api and print the req.method to check what is reached to nextjs

Comment: When i test i also change methods in express routes

Comment: what is your nextjs version ?

Comment: Latest, project was created 5 days ago

Comment: Can you get me working example if you have one. I will try to search my mistake

Comment: no but if you can share your code i can search for that

Comment: for the last guess test this:
```js

 server.post('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })
``` instead of `server.use`

Comment: Thx, i try it tomorrow and i also give you link on git repo tomorrow too.

Comment: Perhaps I'll give you a link today. https://github.com/antoniocra04/strange_error

Comment: all hope for you

Comment: I also remind you that on localhost everything all rigth. Problem only when you deploy on hosting, in my case it is Vercel

Comment: the problem founded. replace `app.use('/api', apiRoutes) ` with `app.use('/api', apiRoutes(app)) `

Comment: When I try to solve problem I try different variants of code and when i push on git i forget remove changes. I already create new commit

Answer (score 0):

Vercel can't use custom server with next js
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13306